# TYPO3, please don't cache link to PDF-file

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, fal

I'm still using `TYPO3 7.6` and my editor upload a new PDF-file via filelist weekly. I told him, that he has to overwrite his current file with the same filename - f.e. `fileadmin/user_upload/editor/1.pdf`

We've insert a Content element `file links` and reference the `1.pdf` from FAL. 
He clear the page cache (flash) every week after uploading. I've set

```
config.cache_period = 604800
config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 0
```

in my setup.typoscript and at page properties, I've also checked: `Cache deactivate`:
[image: deactivate cache via page properties]

**But the website users still see the old PDF-file from last week.** They have to click `F5` manually, to see the current content. That's not good.

How can I linked my FAL-file without cache?
Maybe I should use `config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1`?
Or a direct link via  TypoScript and COA_INT (don't know how exactly? ;) )?
is there a solution with FLUID?

Can some one help and give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Thats probably the browser cache. You can invalidate the file perhaps with the expire header field on the link (1.pdf?expire=timestamp). Or hook the file upload and change the 1.pdf to 1_timestamp.pdf to have in the DOM?

Comment: That has nothing to do with TYPO3. It's your browser cash. You can "force" the browser to download the file again by setting a timestamp to the download link, like: `example.org/my/path/file.pdf?time=1557848376`

Comment: Jep. the individual browser cache from user .i realized it yesterday. How can I set the timestamp to a 'normal' file link in TYPO3? Do I need FLUID here?